# extracting column values while reading the text file

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, while-loop

i have a file saved in text that contain number of rows.I want to read row by row and trying to extract second and third column value at each iteration and want to do some processing with them.(for example while reading first row of the below text file i need to extract value 0.1115 and 0.2 for calculation..

the data i have in the below format and saved in test.txt

```
/home/sio/testfile 0.1115  0.2  0.8
/home/sio/testfile 0.50  0.4  0.1
/home/sio/testfile 0.9  0.7  0.7
/home/sio/testfile 0.4  0.8  0.4
/home/sio/testfile 0.7  0.9  2.3
```

i tried the code below but it gives me error:

```
import numpy as np

a = open("test.txt","r")
b = a.readlines()
a.close()
  while readline(b)
        secondcolumn=
        thirdcolumn=
```

Comment: You are probably looking for `for line in b:` `columns = line.split()`

Comment: how??can you please write it down...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = open("test.txt","r")
b = a.readlines()
a.close()
for line in b:
    columns=line.split()
    if len(columns)>=2:
        col2=columns[1]
        col3=columns[2]
        print(col2,col3)
```